# Mule File Inbound Move to Pattern

Tags: mule

I am processing a text file and works fine except the moveToPattern in the file inbound. After processing the file I need it to be renamed to xxx.processed. For that I am using a moveToPattern. That doesn't seem working. So also its not being deleted although I am setting to autoDelete to true. Below is the code snippet

```
    <file:connector name="Outbound_File" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" pollingFrequency="300000" doc:name="File"  />

<flow name="integrationFlow1" doc:name="integrationFlow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="${inbound.path}" moveToPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename].processed"  responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" connector-ref="Outbound_File" >
        <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="xxx_(.*).txt" caseSensitive="true"/>
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The moveTo feature is an enterprise version feature, as per [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/FTP+Transport+Reference). And it won't work anyhow without the `moveToDirectory` attribute.

The autodelete do work for me, althought you might be hitting an error on some version, are you running the very lastest 3.6.0?

Comment: Thx Victor. We are using 3.5.2 EE. We just upgraded for 3.4.1 EE where its was working.

Comment: That is odd, no new features between those versions, so you have probably found a regression. Given that those two versions are enterprise only, I would recommend you contacting support or just try upgrading to 3.6.0.

Comment: I notice that if I set moveToDirectory same as inbound path then it doesn't seem to work. But if i set moveToDirectory to a different directory its moved to that directory but doesnt rename the file to xxx.processed as in moveToPattern.

Comment: What is the point of having a moveToDirectory to the same than inbound directory? Woudn't that just process the file forever?

Comment: Once I processed I needed to be renamed  from xxx.txt to xxx.processed  in the same directory if at all possible. So if you look at the code snippet I send above i didn't have to moveToDirectory. But for some reason even after the file is processed it not being renamed to xxx.processed. so I tried moveToDirectory along with moveTopattern. But after experimenting I find that if I use a directory other than the directory from where its processed and use the moveToPattern then it works. So is it true that once processed we cant rename the file to xxx.processed in the same directory. Thanks.